# Main differences between lit-element Web Components & React

Tags: reactjs, web-component, lit-element

Looking into React code it seems more similar to "Lit-Element" code, Both can be used to create web components. It is very helpful if someone can explain the main differences between the "React" and "Lit-element"?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

> ## Frameworks *CREATE* HTML,
>
> ## Web Components ***ARE*** HTML

#### *written: october 2020*

[image]

#### React

---

(Over a decade old now, by Facebook/Meta), key feature is its ***virtual*** DOM. That means all DOM elements are created in memory and React is in charge of delivering them to the (real)**DOM**. That also means you can **NOT** do **any** DOM updates yourself, or use the W3C standard Events system.
**everything in the** (real)**DOM** is handled by React.
Great when, like Facebook, you have to prevent thousands of developers messing around in the same DOM. (*There is no slow DOM, only developers writing slow code accessing the DOM*)

**Update 2022** [React R18](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/react-18/text/0000-react-18.md) still doesn't mention Custom Elements/native Web Components

**Update 2024** The *last* React release was 18.2 in june 2022

#### W3C *standard* Web Components (JSWC)

---

[MDN: Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components)

(by: Apple, Mozilla, Google, Microsoft)

Are made up of 3 **distinct** technologies:

- [Custom Elements API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements)
- [Templates: `<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)
- [shadowDOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM)

**each can be used without the other!**

You can attach shadowDOM on a regular `<div>` to create a DIV on steroids, without using Custom Elements or Templates.

The W3C Web Components standard is *defacto* developed by Browser builders Apple, Google, Mozilla & Microsoft.

All of them having to agree, makes for slow progress in setting a standard; but ***once*** a standard, W3C standards are supported for as long as JavaScript will run in the browser.

Web Components history (starting in 2010):

- **must see:** [Video: Web Components: Just in the Nick of Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-8Lmg5Gobw)
- **should see:** [Practical lessons from a year of building web components - Google I/O 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfQoleQEa4w)
- **summary**: https://dev.to/this-is-learning/web-components-101-history-2p24

Microsoft chose to swap Browser-engines and made Edge (january 2020) run on Chromium,
Web Components are supported in **all modern Browsers now**.

Chrome, Safari & FireFox supported Web Components (version V1) **since 2018**.
And some browsers (partially) supported the now deprecated V0 version for  longer.
So there is plenty of experience with Web Components.

- The **Custom Elements API** is an **API**, nothing more, nothing less, (but a powerful one)
  Comparing it to a Framework is like comparing Set and Map to Redux or Vuex.
- **Templates** are great, yet many developers copy/paste blog examples creating a `<template>` with javascript code instead of defining them in HTML
- **shadowDOM** (and `<slot>`s and `:parts`) deserve its own long chapter,
  many developers do not understand what it is or how to use it,
  yet most have a firm opinion on it.

##### All `<input>`, `<textarea>` etc. elements ARE Web Components

All those **standard** HTML tags have been built (for many moons now!) with Web Components technology by the Browser Vendors.

You can tell by opening the Browser Inspector

[image]

All those elements have a `shadow-root`

Note it is a `<user-agent>`(aka Browser) shadow-root, so it is NOT a `open` or `closed` **shadowDOM** us mortal Developers can create/use.
Developers can **not** access `<user-agent>` Web Components.

#### Lit

---

(by Google). Is a library built **on top** of the W3C Web Components technologies

called *Lit-Element* & *Lit-HTML* prior to version 2.
**Before** Lit, Google also had *Polymer*

**!!! You do NOT need Lit to develop Web Components !!!**

Lit is a **tool** It will speed up the development process.
When you learn Lit first, you are learning a **tool** not the Web Components **technology**

Lit is **syntactic sugar** (kinda like jQuery was)

(Just like in early jQuery days) There are **60+ Lit alternatives**:

https://webcomponents.dev/blog/all-the-ways-to-make-a-web-component/

#### A Future for React?

---

The interesting part is React, due to its **virtual** DOM implementation, only supports the W3C Custom Elements API for **71%** (see https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/).
**You** need to create a React wrapper **for each and every** W3C component you want to use.
https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html)

The [React17 update](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html) (october 2020) doesn't even mention the words Web Components, Custom Elements, shadowDOM or Templates

[Update 2021]
I don't read React updates no more. But Benny Powers did:

https://dev.to/bennypowers/what-s-not-new-in-react-18-45c7

**WHATWG**

The very interesting truth is Facebook/Meta has no Browser, and isn't a core member of the WHATWG. And **since 2019**, the WHATWG (read: Google, Apple, Microsoft , Mozilla) are in control of what runs in the Browser:
https://techxplore.com/news/2019-06-w3c-whatwg-agreement-version-html.html

**Frameworks**

**All** other Frameworks (Angular, Vue, Svelte etc.) **do** support the W3C standard 100% **and** can *create* Web Components

## This makes for an interesting future.

- Facebook/Meta, not developing a Browser, hardly has a stake in what Browsers run.
- The WHATWG is *by-invitation-only*; will Google, Apple, Microsoft and Mozilla **invite** Facebook?
- Some say React is the new Flash ([End Of Life: December 31, 2020](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html))
- Some say FaceBook/Meta will merge **W**hatsapp, ins**T**agram and **F**acebook,
  then will provide a new Browser **everyone** in the world ***must*** install

#### On Frameworks and Libraries

---

> Disclaimer: I built my own motorbikes

Frameworks and libraries are like the canned and packed ingredients you buy in the supermarket.

Sure, you get a meal on the table.
But go buy groceries, *taste* spices, learn how to *cut*, *bake* and *grill*,
and you will become a Chef.

One problem with Libraries/Frameworks is: there will always be **breaking changes** in new versions when new features are introduced. OR when features are no longer required because they are now part of the native and thus faster standard (but a different syntax) Think jQuery selectors and the (later implemented) `.querySelector`

It is never a one-click upgrade. And because you most-likely did not write TDD tests for all these new features, **you have to check and test ALL your code again**

Or worse, like with the Google Angular 1 to Angular 2 ***"upgrade"***; you have to rewrite everything...

It is your choice what *professional* Front-End Developer you want to be

[image]

Comment: Haha, what a legendary answer!
Just the predictions are a big much :P

Comment: the last image explains it a lot

Comment: Exactly for this reason, I want to remove my Visual Studio and work with Notepad and .Net CLI  :)