# How can i use my react component as a web component with just a javascript tag call

Tags: reactjs, web-component

I am working on a react app with mapbox that gets data from a JSON file and adds the data on the app.. I have successfully built the app. But what I want now is that I want to be able to use my react-app as a web component. In a way that it will be usable in websites and web apps.

Comment: Do you mean to make another component which the `App.js` app can use?

Comment: No, i mean i want to turn the app into a web-component.
That is i want it to be a web-component, instead of just a normal react app.

Comment: Oh i'm not sure about that then.

Comment: alright, thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Why? What do you want to do with the Web Component what you can't do now? There is no single answer.

Comment: I want to be able to have access to the app in all website and web app..

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way:

Your React application is the U-Haul truck that delivers **everything** from the Web Server (Back-End) to the Browser (Front-End)

[image]

Now you say you want everything wrapped in a (native) Web Component:
`<move-house></move-house>`

It is do-able, but you as the Developer have to develop all **dependencies**

It starts by **fully** understanding what React is and does, so you can wrap **all** its behaviour.

**Unlike** other Frameworks (Angular, Vue, Svelte) React has no "*Make-it-a-Web-Component*" option,
**because** React, with its virtual DOM, is a totally different (and rather outdated) beast that doesn't comply with modern Web Standards. (today [Dec2020] React only scores **71%** on the Custom Elements Everywhere test)

See: https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/libraries/react/results/results.html
for what you as the developer have to fix, because React does not do that for you

Some say React compared to modern JavaScript technologies, Frameworks, Web Component libraries like Lit and Stencil or Svelte, is more like:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I see.. I guess I should have thought of this better before using react..

Comment: Anyways, since it's doable like you said, I would have to develop all dependencies..

Comment: Yes, adding more and more to your already bloated React bundle size.

Comment: How will I go about developing the dependencies.. And will I tweak it into making it work..

Comment: Identify 3 User Stories, Complex, Medium and Easy, and try those. TRY, the objective is to be able to plan the whole project. But before that; WHY do you want this? No 3rd party is going to buy a software solution like this.. unless you have great sales people.

Comment: It's not my personal project, I'm helping a client to build it.. so how he plans to sell it, I have no idea, but what he wants is just a web components that will be resuable.

Comment: Then you have decision to make; tell your client the honest truth, or continue with React, make sure you get paid, and accept the client will curse you a year from now.

Comment: X is the time required to continue with React. Y is the time required to rebuilt the application. You have to calculate if Y < X. Taking into account no 3rd party will buy solution X (a very big bundle) when there will be other options available in the future. You searched the Web for solutions that wrapped React IN a Web Component.. the number of search results is an indication of viability. Think of it this way.. React is the new Flash.. which, this month, is officially dead technology.

Comment: Okay, i get your point,but i have a question tho,  do you think it would have been different if it's a vanilla Javascript?

Comment: No, it just takes longer to develop, but once done it will work for as long as JavaScript runs in a Browser. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304353/main-differences-between-lit-element-react/64307820#64307820

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in react using direflow. https://direflow.io/

Comment: Direflow doesn't appear to be maintained and is not compatible with React 17+.