# How do I render a native web component with Deno?

Tags: web-component, server-side-rendering, deno, oak

I have a native web component (no, not react component)...that I would like to render server side (ssr) in Deno.

Here is the web component:

```
import { api } from '/global.js';

class StatsBar extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
        this.stats = {};
  }

    async getStats() {
        const res = await fetch(`${api}/stats`);
        const data = res.ok && await res.json();
        this.stats = data;
    }


  async connectedCallback() {
        await this.getStats();

    this.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        .stats {
            margin: 2rem 0;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 1rem;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="stats">
            Read <a href="/recent">${this.stats.urls.count.toLocaleString()}</a> articles on <a href="/tags">${this.stats.tags.count.toLocaleString()}</a> topics by ${this.stats.visits.count.toLocaleString()} visitors so far...
    </div>
`;
  }
}

customElements.define("stats-bar", StatsBar);

export default StatsBar;
```

It makes an api to get data, this all works fine client side in browsers, but then google can't crawl it becuase google still doesn't do well with javascript.

I want to see if its possible (With Deno and Oak) to render this component server side.

Comment: Not, the custom elements API is a browser API. Fetch your data server side and create HTML

Comment: So you’re saying don’t use web components server side?

Comment: **the custom elements API is a browser API**

Comment: I thought Deno supported browser api.

Comment: You are most likely getting an answer faster when you read the fine manual: https://deno.land/manual@v1.8.3/runtime/web_platform_apis

Comment: So it isn’t supported? Not sure what I should ascertain from that link.  Is it just a subset of the browser api?

Comment: That page lists the browser APIs supported in Deno, if the custom elements api is not listed, what does that mean...

Comment: But I’ve seen examples for doing ssr with ReactDom plug-in on deno. There must be a way to do it in native web components

Comment: React is outdated tech, it uses virtualDOM, not shadowDOM. Totally different technology, you can't compare the two. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304353/main-differences-between-lit-element-react/64307820#64307820

Comment: Deno doesn't provide a DOM implementation at all.

Comment: No there is `deno-dom` though.