# Seeking insight on performance discrepancy between React and LitElement components

Tags: reactjs, web-component, lit-element, lit, lit-html

I've been conducting performance profiling to compare the rendering efficiency of React and LitElement, specifically focusing on a button component. However, the results are surprising, as LitElement is generally considered faster, yet my profiling tells a different story.

In React, I created a button component that internally calls two sub-components, let's call them Component1 and Component2.

jsx

```
<SampleButton>
   <Component1>
       <Component2>
            <div>
```

After measuring the rendering time, the average came out to be 7ms.

Now, for the LitElement Component, I structured it as follows:

```
html
<sample-button>
     |
  shadow-node
         |
      <lit-component1>
             |
          shadow-node
                |
              <lit-component2>
                     |
                  shadow-node
                       <div>
```

Surprisingly, the rendering time for this LitElement button came out to be 23ms.

I'm a bit puzzled by these results and would like to seek guidance.

How can I refactor or optimize the LitElement component structure? I'm open to suggestions and eager to understand if I might be missing something crucial in my comparison.

Comment: Apples and Oranges; you can't estimate the build time of a 3000 piece Lego set by sticking just 2 Legos together. At least add a Banana and also create this with a native Web Component

Comment: Note, native will be marginally faster than Lit, but slower than this JSX example, React doesn't do shadowDOM... like I said Apples and Oranges

Comment: So I created 2 different project with a button one in react and other purely in lit and then did comparison,
I also extended it by making a card in both and react version of card took 180ms to render it while card written in lit took 270+ms

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman

Comment: React will always be faster creating one block of DOM in virtual DOM, then adding it to the Browser DOM in one block. You are comparing Apples and Oranges. You don't go shopping in a F1 car.

Comment: Thanx @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, but over google I usually see post like lit is faster then react. 
I am little confused here where we should use lit as rendering is faster in react as main concern to select a tech for a project includes performance as well.
We are doing this poc because we want to select lit/react for our project

Thank you for helping in this

Comment: A POC should involve the whole chain. Take building a house, you can't compare using square or re(a)ctangular (pun intended) tiles for a backsplash and then conclude building the whole house with product X or Y is better. In my experience the expertise of the team is the most important factor in selecting a technology. Note: [there are 61 alternatives to Lit](https://webcomponents.dev/blog/all-the-ways-to-make-a-web-component/) Your fundamental choice should be: Do we built with a Browser standard (Web Components), or with React.

Comment: See my React/Lit observations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304353/main-differences-between-lit-element-web-components-react/64307820#64307820 
Chosing a technology by only its technology might be the wrong choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256595/discussion-between-geetanshu-gulati-and-danny-365csi-engelman).